# How can I make my WiFi hotspot secure?

Tags: wireless, security

I just created a wifi hotspot with an adaptor, and it says that it uses WEP security.

[image]

I may be mistaken, but isn't [WEP security not really secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Flaws)? How can I make it more secure, such as WPA or WPA2? I'm quite concerned that someone could access my computer(s).

---

#### Edit

I don't want an answer that is a cure rather than a prevention. I would like stronger encryption, not to individually block people who intrude - by then they may have my data.

It would be acceptable to only allow certain mac address, but I would need an approval process, so that guests could connect to the WiFi without finding their mac addresses.

Comment: Can you switch it to WPA? But if you create an ad-hoc AP, it does not always is possible. MAC filtering does not ad security.

Comment: Since you mentioned MAC address filtering: [*Are MAC Address Filtering and SSID Hiding still worthwhile?* – Information Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/1606/47947)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all :**

In security terms, in the absolute : Wifi or any wireless data system cannot be secured. This is due to the fact that anyone can "ear" you and then "decypher" you.

It means that, if the hacker want to and have the knowledge : he will always win in a short time.

The only thing that you can get is getting the work of hacking you harder.

**That being said, Here is the recommendations without being too specific :**

You are actually connected via WEP and I assume that you use TKIP. Those settings have to be changed directly with the device that provides you Wifi. This must be done first to be able to use something else.

Most of those devices are the Wifi of the DSL box of your provider and mostly only have those settings available. If it's the case : you must purchase a modern Wifi Access Point that you will wire connect to this box in order to shutdown the wifi of the box and use the wifi of the access point you set.

**If you can change your wifi settings or purchased a new wifi access point :**

**WARNING** : Any modification in the wifi device will cause disconnection. If it's badly set then it'll not be able to reconnect. If this happens : connect your computer with an ethernet wire and put again the old setting.

In Wifi security, you have three settings to care about :

- The Wifi password must be more or equal to 14 caracters that must not contain words and must contain letters in upper case and lower case with numbers (no date) and special caracters such as space, @ or #. Think to change your password in a regular basis (at least each semester).
- The key cipher must be WPA2 personal (the other one needs a server that you wouldn't be able to use)
- The cipher must be AES with is more secure than TKIP

Any hardware filtering is quite useless because any hacker will begin by using the hardware ID of any connected existing device. Plus it does not avoid to be listened (and so to be deciphered or hacked). Those protections only block any unknown hardware to speak with them : not to be eard.

But watch out : some wireless devices cannot use those settings (or need update to be able to).

Hopes that will help you.

BTW : WEP+TKIP now takes less than 5 minutes to decipher.

Comment: Cracking WEP took [less than 60 seconds in 2007](http://eprint.iacr.org/2007/120) via http://cre.fm/cre044-wep-is-dead (german)